# I am trying to understand how exactly time complexity is calculated

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I found this question online when practicing:

```
def test1:
 limit = 2
 x="a"
 for i in range(limit):
    for j in range(limit):
      print x

def test2:
 limit = 2
 x="a"
 for i in range(limit):
     print x
 for i in range(limit):
     print x
```

The question was what are the time complexities for `test1` and `test2`? I guess the answer to both is O(n²).

If the limit had been 20 or 30, is it correct that `test2`'s complexity would be be O(2n), which is the same as O(n), and `test1`'s complexity would be O(n²)?

Also what is the complexity if the `for` loop in `test2` is repeated `limit-1` times, where `limit = n`?

Comment: Assuming `n = limit`, the first is O(n^2), the second is O(n) regardless of limit. If limit = `n-1`, the math also doesn't change. I strongly recommend you look at a textbook or reference for how to calculate big O notation, I don't think you really understand it

Comment: Time complexity is all about the *general* effect increasing input size has on an algorithm. `test1` has a nested loop over the same input, so an increase to the input would add `n` iterations. This has an exponential, particularly quadratic, effect on the algorithm. The second uses two, non-nested, loops over the same input. Increasing `limit` doesn't change the iteration's magnitude, however, so it's just O(n).

Answer (score 0):

First of all theory of complexity is quite an interesting field to study, but surely it's not about guessing!!

First of all the complexity of your functions is: `test1 O(N^2)` and `test1 O(N)` but that is surely when assuming that `n = limit` which should be some variable with a certain range of values, i.e. `1 <= n <= 10^5`.

In general in complexity theory we take in consideration variables not constants, because constants with low values will not affect your code (not that huge effect on run time).

And that should answer your last question, when `limit = n; n<=10^5` then when we loop `limit-1` time it's considered as `limit` so the total complexity will remain the same after all.